# Definition of an infinite $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What is the formal definition of an infinite $\sigma$-algebra?

I cannot find this definition anywhere! But based on the context I have read it in I think it is either:

(A)  A $\sigma$-algebra defined on an infinite set $S$ that contains finitely many infinite sets. (i.e. $\{ \emptyset, S\}$ )

(B) A $\sigma$-algebra defined on an infinite set $S$ that contains an infinite number of finite or infinite sets

(C) Any $\sigma$-algebra defined on an infinite set $S$ (i.e. both (A) or (B) are possible)

Comment: Where did you see this term used?

Comment: @MikeF Gerald Folland's "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications", question 1.3 on page 24.

Comment: The answer is (B), an infinite $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra containing infinitely many sets. For that, of course the underlying space must also be infinite (otherwise its power set would be finite).

Comment: The definition of $\sigma$-algebra is independent of any finiteness conditions on the set.

Comment: Royden in his book said that a $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $\mathbb{R}$ and it is closed under complements and countable union.